# Per Sepharadim, is Almond Breeze permissible immediately after meat?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, meat-and-milk

Almond Breeze is described by its manufacturer (Blue Diamond) as being "dairy free [and] made on heated equipment also used for dairy products". The manufacturer also "uses stringent equipment cleaning and testing procedures to ensure that products made on dairy equipment are dairy-free". ([source](http://www.almondbreeze.com/index.cfm?navid=341#q16))

Per Sephardi halakhah, would this product description categorize "Almond Breeze" as being "Noten Ta'am bar Noten Ta'am" and therefore permissible immediately after eating meat?

Comment: Why Sephardim specifically? Is there a relevant difference between Sephardim and Ashkenazim as regards this question?

Comment: While an answer citing a non-Sepharadi poseq would be educational, a Sepharadi pesaq would be more relevant to me personally.

Comment: So you're asking for Pesak.

Comment: I'm not asking someone to personally provide me with a heter or issur; but, I would appreciate having Sepharadi sources on the matter.

Comment: Not just after meat, but even cooked into meat (aside from the maarit ayin issues which arise with almond milk, which can be avoided).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the asker didn't find many many references online to this issue.  The OU, for example, says this:

> 1. The Shulchan Aruch (YD 95:1-2) rules that if a pareve food was cooked in a totally clean dairy vessel, the food may be eaten with meat, and that if a pareve food was cooked in a totally clean meat vessel, the food may be eaten with dairy. The Rema argues and rules that pareve food cooked in a dairy ben yomo (i.e. used with hot dairy in the past 24 hours) vessel may not be eaten with meat, and vice versa, but that b’dieved, if such foods were mixed together, they may be eaten. (Thus, according to the Shulchan Aruch, pareve soup cooked in a totally clean dairy pot could be eaten with meat, whereas the Rema would prohibit it.)

I'm sure a thorough search would find plenty of detailed citations for other halakhic commentaries.  There are also a number of "Ask the Rabbi" sites, and it seems to me that in this case the Ashkinazic rabbis are familiar with the Sephardic halakha.

The short answer (with the caveat of course that I am not a poseq) is that a truly pareve item cooked in dairy equipment can be eaten with meat by Sephardim lekhathila and by Ashkenazim bede'abad; while it can be eaten immediately after meat by everyone lekhathila.

Comment: The op knew this. The question was is almond breeze in this cateory. It's about the reliability of the product description not halachot of Nat bar Nat.